# Laravel Redirect and Change URL

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I thought this would be an easy task and would be the default functionality ... I was wrong.

I am attempting to redirect the user to the dashboard once logged in, I have tried this several ways:

```
return redirect('/dashboard');
return redirect()->to('/dashboard');
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

All of these work to display the dashboard, but they do not change the URL, so you cannot tell the user location from the address. Could someone please tell me what is required to achieve this.

Comment: A Laravel redirect should absolutely change the browser URL.  Are you sure your problem isn't somewhere else?  It sounds like a response somewhere is using `return view('your-dashboard-view');`.

Comment: this is 100% default functionality

Comment: @matticustard you are totally correct, there was a routing issue.  I had both login and dashboard routed on '/', it was running the first route on the initial get request and then the second route on the second request. This did highlight an interesting functionality to me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem & saw that my mistake was in the Route file.

i had twice a time `[..., 'index']` action defined in the same controller

```php
Route::post('/cart', [CheckoutController::class, 'index'])->name('checkout.cart');
Route::get('/checkout', [CheckoutController::class, 'index'])->name('checkout.index');
```